# C# Double Ended Queue for Net 2.1

Tags: c#, nuget

I found [Stephen Cleary's](https://github.com/StephenClearyArchive/Deque) double ended queue for NET 2.0.  When I install it with pm in visual studio Net 2.1 I get this error:

```
"PM> Install-Package Nito.Collections.Deque -Version 1.0.4
Install-Package : Project 'Default' is not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Nito.Collections.Deque -Version 1.0.4
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Default:String) [Install-Package], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetProjectNotFound,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand"
```

Comment: do you have a project default?

Comment: Does possible workaround here help? https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1215

Comment: Please don't use ".NET 2.0" and ".NET 2.1" if what you're actually describing is .NET *Core* versions. Especially because there *was* a .NET 2.0, long ago.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Not long ago; 2005 was just last week

Answer (score 0):

It appears pm was in a bad state.  I rebooted Visual Studio 2017 and the default project appeared.  I was able to install the deque package.

The comments helped me to solve this issue by pointing out to look for where the default project is